# How to jump to a particular date when viewing a person's posts stream on Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I would like to bring up something I or somebody else has shared on Google+ months ago. It is time consuming to just scroll down and down and down, clicking `more` and `more`.

Can I just jump to a particular date instantly?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google+ was shut down in April, 2019.

Answer (score 0):

#### [Google Plus supports advanced search terms](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1669519):

As for your question, here's an example:

- [`before: 2015/3/14`](https://plus.google.com/s/before%3A2015%2F3%2F14/top)
- [`after: 2014-03-14`](https://plus.google.com/s/after%3A%202014-03-14/top)

Note you can join phrases with `AND, OR & NOT` to refine better your search:

> #### AND, OR & NOT
>
> You can refine your search to include multiple queries or exclude certain terms by using logic operators. Enter these operators in all capital letters.
>
> **Tip:** You can search for multiple operators without use of the word "AND." You can also replace "NOT" with a minus sign.

More possible phrases:

- `in/community/collection`
- `from:me/from:userid`
- `has:video/has:attachment`
- `commenter:...`
- `mention:...`

Read more on [Search in Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1669519)